# PL/SQL: delete row inside cursor not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-delete

how do I delete rows from a table inside a PL/SQL cursor loop? Guess, I'm doing something wrong with this code:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR myCursor IS SELECT * FROM A WHERE <some-condition> FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN myCursor LOOP
    DELETE FROM A WHERE CURRENT OF myCursor;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If I replace the `DELETE` statement with an `UPDATE`, everything works as expected (beside that the record only gets updated instead of deleted). For example:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR myCursor IS SELECT * FROM A WHERE <some-condition> FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN myCursor LOOP
    UPDATE A SET FOO = 'bar' WHERE CURRENT OF myCursor;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Why are you using a cursor in the first place? You could replace this slow-by-slow processing using a single statement: `delete from a where <some-condition>`. But you need at least explain what "not working" means. It is **not** a valid Oracle error message

Comment: Actually these statements are part of a procedure - I just stripped it down for better readablility. "not working" means, that when I want to save/compile the procedure, I get an "SQL statement ignored" for the `DELETE ...` part.

Comment: Ok, never mind ... just figured out, that the actual problem was rather a missing `DELETE` permission (table `A` is in schema `foo`, while the procedure itself is in schema `bar`)

Comment: I hope your query is just an example, not the real code. Actually it should work, see [SELECT FOR UPDATE and FOR UPDATE Cursors](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS603). However, check the restrictions: [Restrictions on the FOR UPDATE Clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55371)